# New close descriptions cool, but annoying

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make new close reasons dialog experience-sensitive.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38680/make-new-close-reasons-dialog-experience-sensitive)

I used to click "close" to vote to close things. I would get a tooltip with the reasons for closing, and I'd pick one and press enter, and then I'd be done.

Now I click "close" to vote to close things, and I get a ginourmous tooltip with the reasons for closing and paragraphs explaining each one in detail, and I have to scroll to pick the reason I want half the time.

I think the expanded tooltip is a great idea, but perhaps it should revert back to the original, shorter version for users over a certain reputation threshold, or who have cast a certain number of close votes, or are otherwise experienced enough that we can trust them to understand the close reasons.

Comment: you've been duped.

Comment: But I can't find it, and it's bedtime.  Pretty recent, though.  Lots of people complained about it.

Comment: I'm sure the new close box is truly awesome on a netbook.

Comment: @Greg: Yes, it takes up more than my screen height, even on Chrome with bookmarks gone.

Comment: I haven't gone to bed yet.  Silly me.  Here's the dupe, in case you don't want to click "close" and find out yourself: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38680/make-new-close-reasons-dialog-experience-sensitive

Comment: @Greg - You should check it out on an iPhone!

Comment: @Pollyanna iPhone + SO = a world of hurt.

Comment: @alex no, because we disable WMD when iPhone user agents are detected. And are you REALLY closing items on an iPhone?

Comment: greasemonkey to the rescue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38680/make-new-close-reasons-dialog-experience-sensitive/38756#38756