# Annoying UX while voting to close questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was doing my usual trawl through the [Flagged Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged) page, and finally got annoyed enough about this 'feature' to raise a question about it. This close vote confirmation/information tooltip is what annoys me:

[image]

**The problem:** *I don't need it.*
**Why?** *I really don't care what it has to say.*

**Let me explain why this feature makes an annoying UX for me**
Once I have cast my vote, I move on to the next flagged question. I have a great interest in keeping SO clean and tidy, but I have almost zero interest in the specific question I just voted on. I can also add up to five without any help - if a question already has two close votes, then I cast mine, I know that it will require two more - basic arithmetic, I don't need to be told<sup>1</sup>. If it collects enough votes to be closed then fantastico!! If it doesn't, then que será, será, so be it<sup>2</sup>. If someone else added a close vote at the same time as me, I still don't really care.

Now add to that the fact that I am voting on numerous questions. When the tooltip pops up, it obscures part of the title of the next entry, and I have to make an extra click to get rid of it immediately.

Maybe that tooltip is useful the first 5 times you see it, but it certainly isn't when you've seen it for the 1000th time.

I also know of [this  question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39037/new-close-descriptions-cool-but-annoying) and [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38680/make-new-close-reasons-dialog-experience-sensitive), my question talks about the same thing but in a different location. And those questions are 18 months old.

<sup>1</sup> If you want to make it interesting, change the base of the number shown. Just to be different, make it base 3.

<sup>2</sup> Apologies to any Spanish speakers for this butchering of your language - blame Hollywood.

Comment: I think it is _che sarà, sarà_ ("what will be will be"), which is Italian, not Spanish. `:-)`

Comment: [It's Que Sera Sera, which isn't really anything](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Que_Sera,_Sera_%28Whatever_Will_Be,_Will_Be%29)

Comment: @kiamlaluno umm... it is spanish...

Comment: I hate that this feature is even there in the first place. It only display part of the question. So all this does is make people close questions without actually read them in their entirety.

Answer (score 8):

What is reported in the dialog box is also incorrect: A question can be closed with less users than what is reported, if a moderator votes to close it.
The reported number is the maximum number of users required to close the question, but I don't see the point of reporting that, as the maximum number of users required to close a question doesn't change, and it is already stated in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close).

Comment: Exactly. I should be getting a tooltip for results or events that are **not** expected, like *Uh oh, you cannot vote because you have no votes left*, rather than for things which just worked the way a user would expect them to work.

Comment: Generally when a moderator closes it isn't considered a "vote". In any case, the UI intentionally ignores moderators all over the place, since it would get a little old to tack on "...except for mods" everywhere

Comment: @MichaelMrozek A moderator's vote is called _blinding vote_; I would get it still a vote. The point I am trying to make is that the information is misleading, and not necessary. There are cases where the number of votes changes, such as the case of voting for delete a question (if I remember correctly), but in this case, the number of votes is always the same (if a moderator doesn't vote to close).