# Large amount of text to close a question

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, usability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make new close reasons dialog experience-sensitive.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38680/make-new-close-reasons-dialog-experience-sensitive)

The option to close a question on SO has now ballooned to a large amount of text. Is this really necessary? Shouldn't the explanations be as a tool tip instead?

I operate with a resolution of 1440x900 and I found it to take up the screen to the point where I have to scroll to see all of it.

(This is an exact copy and paste from the box itself; don't kill the messenger)

> #### Why should this question be closed?
>
> - **exact duplicate**
>            This question covers exactly the same ground as earlier questions on this topic; its answers may be merged with another identical question.
> - **not programming related**
>            Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way. This question is very far afield from programming.
> - **subjective and argumentative**
>     It's impossible to objectively answer this question; questions of this type are too open ended and usually lead to confrontation and argument.
> - **not a real question** 
>     It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.
> - **too localized**
>            This question would only be relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.
> - **belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com**
>            This question is a discussion of this web site or community itself, and is a better fit for Meta Stack Overflow.
> - **belongs on serverfault.com**
>     This question is server or system administration related, and is a better fit for Server Fault.
> - **belongs on superuser.com**
>     This question is related to computer hardware or computer software in general, and is a better fit for Super User.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38680/make-new-close-reasons-dialog-experience-sensitive