# Have you modded your SO interface?

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface, userscript

Stack Overflow really has a nice clean interface, but I always find some little things I like to tweak - with Stylish and/or Greasemonkey - in the sites I visit most.

So far I have replaced Arial (I really can't stand that font) with Droid Sans and also replaced the fixed width font with Droid Sans Mono. I also switched off the little red `x` from the interesting/ignored tag boxes on top right -- I believe they look a lot better without those, and I can remove them from my profile's pref page.

So I'm curious, have you tweaked your interface and how?

Comment: Should be community wiki...

Comment: There's not such thing as 'Should be community wiki' on meta

Comment: see http://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts for the official directory of scripts!

Answer (score 11):

No, I want to experience the site as the creators intended it

Comment: I bet you're one of those people who only buys widescreen DVDs too!

Comment: @Tom: you say that like its a bad thing. :)

Comment: @Tom: Yes, and I did that back before I had a widescreen TV, too!

Answer (score 3):

No.  I can understand why one might do that, but I use several different' computers to access SO based on a circumstances, and I don't want to have to synchronize all my mods amongst them.

I'm waiting for the API so I can use a single, customizable web interface to access all the stackexchange sites I visit.

I'm guessing we'll have an API in 6-8 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few greasemonkey scripts I've started using.  It's more about functionality than looks:

- [Extended top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/greasemonkey-script-to-show-profile-reputation-and-badges-from-all-so-sites-in), the most look-changing.  I use it more for the links than the extra graphics, and have been thinking about modding it to match my preferences.
- [Revert the close-reason dialogue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38680/make-new-close-reasons-dialog-experience-sensitive/38756#38756) from wall-o'-text to reasonably-sized.
- [Show latest activity glyph](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38738/greasemonkey-script-to-show-latest-activity-in-question-overview) for the front page.

Answer (score 1):

I have, but only in a very minor fashion. I adjusted the inline code fonts to clean up the ["river" effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33709/formatting-of-inline-code-is-ugly-and-can-result-in-river-like-patterns-when-used/33764#33764) a bit. I haven't felt much need to go farther than that; the rest of the UI is fine for me.

Also, I added a couple of GreaseMonkey scripts now:

- SO Dupecloser
- SO Show Today's Reputation
- SO Tag Votes and Tag Badges

Comment: re: dupecloser.  is that this one? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21826/greasemonkey-easier-vote-to-close-for-duplicates

Comment: @~quack: Yes. Yes it is. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've tweaked my entire meta-UI:

[Did you ever wish you could have a Hot Dog Stand-themed meta.stackoverflow.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34939/did-you-ever-wish-you-could-have-a-hot-dog-stand-themed-meta-stackoverflow-com)

Answer (score 0):

[Yes](http://i385.photobucket.com/albums/oo300/new123456_photos/Screenshot.png)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name UIOverflow
// @description Pretty up the SE sites
// @include http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @incldue http://superuser.com/*
// @include http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include http://serverfault.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

function xpath(query) {
    return document.evaluate(query, document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
}

function removeByXPath(query){
    var foos, foo;
    foos = xpath(query);

    for (var bar = 0; bar < foos.snapshotLength; bar++){
        foo = foos.snapshotItem(bar);
        foo.parentNode.removeChild(foo);
    }
}

function removeById(id){
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    if (x) x.parentNode.removeChild(x);
}


// Ads
removeByXPath('//*[@class="everyonelovesstackoverflow"]');
removeByXPath('//*[@class="hireme"]');
removeByXPath('//div[@class="user-gravatar32"]');
removeByXPath('//div[@class="user-action-time"]');

// Make the sidebar bg grey
var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");
if (sidebar) { sidebar.style.backgroundColor = "CCCCCC"; }

// Remove some cruft links at the top and bottom
removeById("hlinks-custom");
removeById("footer");
```

Comment: XPath is slow. Why not use `document.querySelectorAll`?

Comment: @YiJiang Never heard of it, actually. How much faster?