# Can the Stack Exchange sites communicate with one another?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Is there a way for you to tag a question on my StackExchange site, and it suggest another SE site?

For example, I am on Stack Overflow, and I tag one of my questions as `Windows Server 2008`.  Can the StackExchange network fire up, search for tags on other SE sites and suggest sites were that tag is used more.  In the example, it would suggest ServerFault (I think).

I guess my question is more along the lines of ... can the SE sites communicate with each other?

Comment: Hmmm... this could, in theory, be covered by [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66715/add-a-search-box-to-stackexchange-com).

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is what question migration is for:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/migrate-questions-between-websites/

You may also be interested in:

[Will it be possible to migrate questions between the trilogy and the Stack Exchange 2.0 sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52141/will-it-be-possible-to-migrate-questions-between-the-trilogy-and-the-stack-exchan)

[Adapt close dialog UI for upcoming avalanche of StackExchange 2.0 graduates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63961/adapt-close-dialog-ui-for-upcoming-avalanche-of-stackexchange-2-0-graduates)

Comment: I guess so ... but that isn't very cool.  It would be cooler if you made it look like SE had some AI, and interrupted the user with a clippy telling them, "I think you want to ask this question on Server Fault".

Comment: @Martin not sure whether you mean this as a joke or a serious suggestion. If it's a serious suggestion: this would never work. Imagine a programming problem that occurs only on Windows Server 2008 - perfectly okay to ask on SO, and tag `Windows-server-2008`. An "AI" for this would take man-years to develop and require constant fine-tuning. What's wrong with the current process?

Comment: @Pekka's: Of course it could work. A simple "AI" is already described in the original post. It would just give a suggestion, so "a programming problem that occurs only on Windows Server 2008" is not a problem.